# What username and password is needed for JavaMail API?

Tags: java, swing, email, netbeans

I'm trying to learn how to send an email using a Netbeans application. Whenever I run the application, I keep getting the following error:

`javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.`

I got code from two different sources (specified below) and both give the exact same error. I used the correct `.jar` files, and the code was copied exactly as shown in the tutorials, but neither works. I also tried using my proper Gmail credentials (made sure they were 100% correct) and I still get the error.

What I want to know is:

What do I use as username and password? (are there predefined ones I need to obtain or do I need to create them, and if so how?)

**Sources:**

This one does not specify a password anywhere at all: [Email: How to send email using java Netbeans [Tutorial] - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01MWjRVBjzI)

This one specifies a password as `String pass = "****";` which I changed to `String pass = "pass123";`: [Send email using Java (in NetBeans)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4rWdPvNI4Q)

Comment: username and password of your email/sender email

Comment: so basically my Gmail account credentials?

Comment: I tried that and I still get the error. When I tried my credentials, I made sure that the username and password was 100% correct.

Comment: Maybe you have enabled [two-way authentication](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/). If that is the case, you need to replace the normal Gmail password with the generated [application specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) in your code.

Comment: I found the error after Gmail sent me a message on my phone about a less secure app trying to sign into my account. But thanks guys for your assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found out the answer. The thing that was causing the error was:

Gmail actually prevented the application from sending the email from the Java application because it read it as a "Less secure app" trying to sign in to my account.

A few relevant changes and the application works now

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have downloaded the required jars to fulfill Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.

Now when you want to connect with Gmail account programmatically then you have to enable the allow less secure apps. You can do that by using the following link.

If you access more times repeatedly then the access can be blocked by Google and even Google will intimate with **Critical Security Alerts**

[Allow Less secured Apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)